# JQuery plugin Lightbox images are not showing up

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using Lokesh Dashkar's Lightbox Jquery plugin: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. I followed the instruction, but for some reason, my image is not loading. What could be the possible issue?

I put in both files:

```
<link href="../portfolio/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../portfolio/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

And then for the HTML, I put in:

```
<a href="media/me.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

I use JS to customize it, and put the script right below the HTML code above:

```
<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you follow these steps correctly?

1. Include the Javascript at the bottom of your page before the closing </body> tag:
<script src="path/to/lightbox.js"></script>

2. Make sure jQuery, which is required by Lightbox, is also loaded.

Comment: I included the javascript at the bottom of the page before closing body tag and the css before the closing head tag. Am I supposed to leave it as path/to/lightbox.js? Instead of changing the path to fit my local settings? @SMAhmed

Comment: No, path can be modified according to your need. Can you include a fiddle?

Comment: Put your script after loading the lightbox js, that is after this <script src="path/to/lightbox.js"></script>

Comment: Ah that works! Thank you. I didn't realize that you had to put both paths. Still a beginner web developer.

Comment: Can you actually explain why though you would need to include both files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111824/discussion-between-sm-ahmed-and-dancemc15).